LR not decaying for pytorch AdamW even after hundreds of epochs
I have following code using AdamW optimizer from pytorch:
optimizer = AdamW(params=self.model.parameters(), lr=0.00005)

I tried to log it using wandb as follows:
lrs = {f'lr_group_{i}': param_group['lr']
       for i, param_group in enumerate(self.optimizer.param_groups)}
wandb.log({"train_loss": avg_train_loss, "val_loss": val_loss, **lrs})

Note that default value for weight_decay parameter is 0.01 for AdamW.
When I checked wandb dashboard, it showed same LR for AdamW even after 200 epochs and it was not decaying at all. I tried this in several runs.

Why the LR decay is not happening?
Also it was showing LR for only one param group. Why is it so? It seem that I miss something basic here. Can someone point out?

As the parameter name as well as the algorithm on the documentation indicate, AdamW decays the model weights and does not directly change the learning rate as you seem to be understanding. Section 2 in the original paper of AdamW gives more in-depth information on weight decay in neural networks.

You have a misunderstanding of the terminology. Weight decay is a process whereby a model is punished at each training iteration for having high weights. In the case of L2 regularization, this is done by multiplying some factor (which in your case would be 0.01) with the sum of squares of all the weights. The resulting number is then added to the final loss, and thus we say that the model is "punished" because high weights result in high loss in our new definition of the loss function.
The reason why doing something like this is useful is because, especially in the case of large neural networks, extreme values for weights suggests overfitting (memorization). Conceptually, you can think of this as you driving a car, and constantly jerking the steering wheel around to form a bizarre zig-zag path around some obstacles in the road. In this analogy, you've "overfit" to the geometry of the road, aka your dataset. Weight decay is like if your steering wheel zapped you at you every time you turned it too fast, thus forcing you to take a smoother route.
Thus, by enforcing weight decay, we can prevent our models from overfitting.
If you're looking for learning rate decay, then it looks like from the PyTorch documentation for AdamW that there isn't learning rate decay functionality built in. So, if you want to achieve the same effect, then every time you want your learning rate to decay you can simply do:
lr *= lr_decay_rate

Note that you would need to re-initialize your optimizer each time you do this. There also might be some other function in pytorch with learning rate decay built in, but I'll leave that up to you to find.
Hope this helps!
